# open-uri and sax parsing for a giant xml document

Tags: ruby, xml, sax, open-uri

I need to connect to an external XML file to download and process (300MB+).
Then run through the XML document and save elements in the database.

I am already doing this no problem on a production server with [Saxerator](https://github.com/soulcutter/saxerator) to be gentle on memory.  It works great.  Here is my issue now --

I need to use open-uri (though there could be alternative solutions?) to grab the file to parse through.  This problem is that open-uri has to load the whole file before anything starts parsing, which defeats the entire purpose of using a SAX Parser to save on memory... any work arounds?  Can I just read from the external XML document?  I cannot load the entire file or it crashes my server, and since the document is updated every 30 minutes, I can't just save a copy of it on my server (though this is what I am doing currently to make sure everything id working).

I am doing this Ruby, p.s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try Net::HTTP's [streaming interface](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#class-Net%3a%3aHTTP-label-Streaming+Response+Bodies) instead of open-URI. This will give Saxerator (via the underlying Nokogiri::SAX::Parser) an IO object rather than the entire file.

Comment: Just wanted to say that I implemented this and works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I took a few minutes to write this up and then realized you tagged this question with ruby. My solution is in Java so I apologize for that. I'm still including it here since it *could* be useful to you or someone down the road.

This is always how I've processed large external xml files

```
XMLReader xmlReader = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser().getXMLReader();
xmlReader.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces", true);
XMLFilter filter = new XMLFilterImpl();

filter.setParent(xmlReader);

filter.parse(new InputSource(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new URL("<url to external document here>").openConnection().getInputStream(),"UTF8"))));
```