# How to stream large xml in Rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm migrating our app from 3.0 to 3.2.x. Earlier the streaming was done by the assigning the response_body a proc. Like so:

```
self.response_body = proc do |response, output|
  target_obj = StreamingOutputWrapper.new(output)
  lib_obj.xml_generator(target_obj)
end
```

As you can imagine, the StreamingOutputWrapper responds to `<<`.

This way is deprecated in Rails 3.2.x. The suggested way is to assign an object that responds to `each`.

The problem I'm facing now is in making the `lib_obj.xml_generator` each-aware.

The current version of it looks like this:

```
def xml_generator(target, conditions = [])
  builder = Builder::XmlMarkup.new(:target => target)
  builder.root do
    builder.elementA do
      Model1.find_each(:conditions => conditions) { |model1| target << model1.xml_chunk_string }
    end
  end
end
```

where `target` is a `StreamingOutputWrapper` object.

The question is, how do I modify the code - the xml_generator, and the controller code, to make the response xml stream properly.

**Important stuff**: Building the xml in memory is not an option as the model records are huge. The typical size of the xml response is around 150MB.

Comment: Sax parsing? Have you looked into the Saxerator gem? It totally rules and makes SAX Parsing simple and easy.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is SAX Parsing.  SAX reads files "chunks" at a time instead of loading the whole file into DOM.  This is super convenient and fortunately there are a lot of people before you who have wanted to do the same thing. [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/SAX.html) offers XML::SAX methods, but it can get really confusing in the disastrous documentation and syntactically, it's a mess.  I would suggest looking into something that sits on top of Nokogiri and makes getting your job done, a lot more simple.

Here are a few options -

---

[SAX_stream](https://github.com/craigambrose/sax_stream):

Mapping out objects in sax_stream is super simple:

```
require 'sax_stream/mapper'

class Product
  include SaxStream::Mapper

  node 'product'
  map :id,             :to => '@id'
  map :status,         :to => '@status'
  map :name_confirmed, :to => 'name/@confirmed'
  map :name,           :to => 'name'
end
```

and calling the parser in is also simple:

```
require 'sax_stream/parser'
require 'sax_stream/collectors/naive_collector'

collector = SaxStream::Collectors::NaiveCollector.new
parser = SaxStream::Parser.new(collector, [Product])

parser.parse_stream(File.open('products.xml'))
```

---

However, working with the collectors (or writing your own) and end up being slightly confusing, so I would actually go with:

[Saxerator](https://github.com/soulcutter/saxerator):

Saxerator gets the job doen and has some really handy methods for traversing into nodes that can be a little less complex than sax_stream.  Saxerator also has a few really great configuration options that are well documented.  Simple Saxerator example below:

```
parser = Saxerator.parser(File.new("rss.xml"))

parser.for_tag(:item).each do |item|
  # where the xml contains <item><title>...</title><author>...</author></item>
  # item will look like {'title' => '...', 'author' => '...'}
  puts "#{item['title']}: #{item['author']}"
end

# a String is returned here since the given element contains only character data
puts "First title: #{parser.for_tag(:title).first}"
```

---

If you end up having to pull the XML from an external source (or it is getting updated frequently and do you don't want to have to update the version on your server manually, check out [THIS QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21634792/open-uri-and-sax-parsing-for-a-giant-xml-document) and the accepted answer, it works great.

Comment: I don't think I need Saxerator for this, as I'm not reading an already existing xml file. From a controller action, I want to render an xml that is dynamically built using builder. And since the xml embeds thousands of database records, I want to stream it **as it is being built by the Builder**.

Comment: saxerator writes files too, that's actually what I use it for most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

You could always monkey-patch the response object:

```
response.stream.instance_eval do
  alias :<< :write
end
builder = Builder::XmlMarkup.new(:target => response.stream)
...
```

Comment: I tried this.....does not work.  The ActionDispatch::Response::Buffer  @buf  had all the xml markup, but it never was flushed.  Rails 4.2.x with Ruby 2.1.7.  Comm between client <-> rails app 1 <-> rails app 2 <-> s3.  I have the xml streaming all the way, but between the client <-> rails app 1 I need to translate or process the XML.    Saxerator does chunk read, but as I build the new XML, it does not stream it to the client.